# Non-free quotient of the canonical sphere Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider $S^d := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}: \|x\|_2 = 1\}$ with its canonical structure inherited from $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ as a Riemannian manifold.

Consider now $S^d_{\geq 0}:= \{x \in S^d: \forall i \in \{1, \dots, d+1\}, x_i \geq 0\}$. What sort of structure can I inherit from $S^d$ on this set? I can view $S^d_{\geq 0}$ as the quotient of $S^d$ by the group generated by reflections along coordinate axes but the Quotient Manifold Theorem does not apply as this action is not free.

I would expect $S^d_{\geq 0}$ to be a smooth manifold with corners but can I also get a Riemannian metric from the sphere?

Comment: Sure, $S^d_{\ge 0}$ is homeomorphic to the compact $d$-dimensional disc which is homeomorphic to a hemisphere of $S^d$, so you can just use [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure) to pull back the smooth structure and Riemannian metric on $S^d$ using a homeomorphism from $S^d_{\ge 0}$ to a hemisphere of $S^d$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for this, that is very helpful! I think I understand the idea of going from, say, the upper hemisphere of $S^d$ to $S^d_{\geq 0}$. However, I don't fully understand the step from $S^d$ to the hemisphere.

My understanding is that the hemisphere is a manifold with boundary but the sphere does not have a boundary. It therefore seems strange to me that I would be able to inherit the structure from $S^d$ easily?

Comment: A closed hemisphere of $S^d$ naturally has the structure of a submanifold-with-boundary of $S^d$, and it inherits its Riemannian metric by restricting the standard Riemannian metric on $S^d$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Excellent, that makes sense! If you combine your comments into an answer, I will accept.